# fetch data from couch db use pagination and without using startkey , endKey in hyperledger fabric

Tags: javascript, java, go, couchdb

how to fetch data from couch db use pagination and
without using start_key , end_Key in Hyper Ledger fabric

Comment: use limit and skip

Comment: `skip` is OK for very small values - say 1 - but for large values a significant performance hit can arise because *each* row is still processed by the server.